# Gradle DSL Method not found: 'andapply()'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following build error when I try to sync my project:

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'andapply()'

I imported this project today from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Here is the **build.gradle** file from the project directory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

But the problem comes frome here:

```
andapply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.seamansbutton"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
andapply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

is your problem, it should be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: It was that easy? Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

Where you put...

```
andapply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

... it should be `apply plugin`, not `andapply plugin`.